# React-Native not able to connect to a Node.js server (Network request failed onerror)

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I am trying to make a simple React Native app able to send data to a Node.js server.

Nonetheless I get a 'Network request failed' error...

It is the first time I'm trying to implement this kind of project so I may have done a stupid mistake but it's been 2 days I've been unable to find

Thanks for any help or advice!

This is my app code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native' //import des components natifs
import {StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const io = require('socket.io-client');
let socket = io('https://localhost:8080');

class Connexion extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
 }

validationConnexion(){
    fetch('https://localhost:8080', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'text/plain',
        },
    }).catch((error) => {             
        console.error(error);
        });
}
```

On the backend side:

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https')
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = https.Server(app, function(req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
   res.end();})
const websocket = socketio(server);
server.listen(8080, () => console.log('listening on *:8080'));

// The event will be called when a client is connected.
websocket.on('connection', (socket) => {
     console.log('A client just joined on', socket.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try your IP address instead of localhost

For example:

https://localhost:8080 to https://192.*.*.*:8080

Comment: I also tried it but unfortunately it didn't work... but thanks for your help!